# Formation Of Sets

Tags: combinatorics

I don't know whether the theorem below is true or not. If true, is there any proof of the theorem.

> Number of ways of dividing $l_1$ sets containing $p_1$ objects each and $l_2$ sets containing $p_2$ objects each and so on.. is equal to $\frac{n!}{(p_1)!^{l_1}(p_2)!^{l_2}.......(p_k)!^{l_k}(l_1)!(l_2)!.....(l_k)!}$.

Where $(l_1)(p_1)+(l_2)(p_2).....+(l_k)(p_k)=n$

Comment: Yes, you can resemble groups as sets

Comment: Thanks for correcting me I didn't knew that

Comment: No problem :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)  It is interesting subject... Give it a try when you have time.. I am hesistating to say that sets and elements are used together and not sets and objects.. There is something called category.. category and objects are used together... sets and elements are used together... may be just a choice of words for now but in advanced mathematics it might cause some confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{i=1}^kl_ip_i = n$$

Now, make $k$ rows, such that each row contains $l_ip_i$ objects. Further divide the $i^{th}$ row in $l_i$ block each containing $p_i$ objects. Now, there are $n!$ ways of arranging the $n$ objects and each such arrangement corresponds to an arrangement of objects in these $k$ rows we have made. Now, call two objects to be in same group if they are in same block. This gives rise to two kinds of repetitions in calculating the number of groupings, as follows.

In every row, we can permute the blocks among each other keeping the groupings same. Thus we have $l_i!$ repetitions in the $i^{th}$ row and thus we have to divide $n!$ by $l_1!l_2!\cdots l_k!$.

Also, we can permute the elements in a block among themselves keeping the same groupings. Thus we have $(p_i!)^{l_i}$ in $i^{th}$ row. Hence, the total number of required groupings are $$\frac{n!}{l_1!l_2!\cdots l_k!\times (p_1!)^{l_2}(p_2!)^{l_2}\cdots (p_k!)^{l_k}}$$

Hope it helps:)

Comment: What if $$\sum_{i=1}^kl_ip_i < n$$ ??

Comment: Then $n-\sum_{i=1}^kl_ip_i$ is another group.